# "No root file system is defined"

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS by USB on my newly built custom PC and I have run into a problem during installation with the error saying

> No root file system is defined.

My PC specifications:

- AMD Phenom x4 955 Black Edition
- ASRock 960GM/U3S3 FX Micro ATX AM3+ Motherboard
- Mushkin Redline 8GB (2x4GB) DDR3-1866 Memory
- Seagate Barracuda 1.5TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive
- XFX Radeon HD 7850 1GB Video Card
- XFX 550W 80 PLUS Bronze Certified ATX12V / EPS12V Power Supply

Everything is new.

Answer (score 2):

At the partitioning step, select the partition you want to have Ubuntu installed on, click the "Change" button, and select `/` as "Mount point". Then click "Install now".

Answer (score 0):

You should do the custom installation and follow [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_trEVXBgLg) to a video guide that will help you through the steps. It was a quick search on Youtube. His voice is low so you might want to turn it up a bit. The video will show you how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

For that partition where you install Linux chose "**/**" as mount option, for Swap partition chose "**SWAP**" and for Data partitions choose "**/home**".